# increment date by month using python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I know there are some post regarding this matter however I want to keep my current format since to me it is most readable.

```
dates = [str(date) for date in np.array("2019-06-14", dtype=np.datetime64) + np.arange(14)]
```

This creates list of dates which increments by day, how can I increase by months?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [481]: np.arange(0,10, dtype='datetime64[M]')                                
Out[481]: 
array(['1970-01', '1970-02', '1970-03', '1970-04', '1970-05', '1970-06',
       '1970-07', '1970-08', '1970-09', '1970-10'], dtype='datetime64[M]')


In [482]: _.astype('datetime64[D]')                                             
Out[482]: 
array(['1970-01-01', '1970-02-01', '1970-03-01', '1970-04-01',
       '1970-05-01', '1970-06-01', '1970-07-01', '1970-08-01',
       '1970-09-01', '1970-10-01'], dtype='datetime64[D]')    

In [511]: np.arange('2019-06-01',6, dtype='datetime64[M]')+np.timedelta64(13,'D'
     ...: )                                                                     
Out[511]: 
array(['2019-06-14', '2019-07-14', '2019-08-14', '2019-09-14',
       '2019-10-14', '2019-11-14'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```